# How to gain access to specific pdf informations?

Tags: java

i have project going in jav where i need to filter out the following Informations out of Science PDF-Documents.
Author, Title and References.
There are several Problems with getting these specific Informations out of an PDF dokument.
1.There is no specific way in Writing a Paper so every paper looks different.
2.For a Programm it is hard to differentiate between names and actuall described objects.
and there are some more problems but this would take us too far away from my actuall question.
My question is, is there a option to gain accsess to certain kind of Information in a Pdf Dokument,
like which font sizes are been used in this pdf or what kind of different fonts are used?
Are there any methods or editors with which i can look inside a pdf in understandable way so i maybe can find iconic features around the Informations i need. So that i can wirte a algorythem to extract them properly.
Thx for your help.
And i am sorry for my english it is not my native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an SDK such as [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to read the properties of a PDF file, as well as other file contents.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, should it solve your problem :)

Comment: Sorry . Accepted it now.